# add arrows in ParametricPlot3D plots

Tags: plotting, graphics3d

I'd like to know if there is a simple way of adding arrows in specified positions. For example, given

```
ParametricPlot3D[{1 + Sqrt[2] Cos@t,-Sqrt[2] Sin@t,3 + 2 Sqrt[2] Cos@t}, {t, 0, 2 Pi}]
```

how could I add arrows (with the same orientation as the curve) at `t = 0, Pi`?

Comment: See [`Epilog`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Epilog.html)

Comment: I closed your question as a duplicate. Don't worry about this, it just means that we already have a post that answers your question. It took me a while to find it, but I believe it is exactly what you want.

Answer (score 3):

```
ParametricPlot3D[{1 + Sqrt[2] Cos@t, -Sqrt[2] Sin@t, 3 + 2 Sqrt[2] Cos@t}, {t, 0, 2 Pi}, 
  PlotStyle -> Arrowheads[{{.05, 0}, {.05, Pi/2/Pi}},  Appearance -> "Projected"]] /. 
 Line -> Arrow
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot! That’s exactly what I needed.